# Waterline datatime validation: new Date() rejected

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, sails.js, waterline

One of my Sails/Waterline models is defined thus:

```
/**
 * Meeting.js
 */

module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    datetime: {
      type: 'datetime',
      required: true,
    },

    agenda: {
      model: 'agenda',
    },

    minutes: {
      model: 'minutes',
    },
  }
};
```

I've got a controller whose job is to stuff test data into the database. Part of it is as follows (coffeescript):

```
create: (req, res) ->
  meeting = Meeting.create(
    datetime: new Date(),
  ).exec((err, new_meeting) ->
    return res.negotiate(err) if err
    # do more stuff
  )
```

However, when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
"invalidAttributes": {
  "datetime": [
    {
      "rule": "datetime",
      "message": "Value should be a datetime (instead of 1497312500210, which is a number)"
    }
  ]
},
// and so on
```

Why is this validation failing? I'm passing in a `Date` object. Since JavaScript doesn't have a `datetime` object, `Date` is obviously the right thing to pass. Except that Waterline doesn't like it. What does Waterline want?

In case it isn't obvious, I'm quite new to node, Sails, Waterline, etc. I mostly deal with Python.

Comment: `1497312500210` is a time value representing 2017-06-13T00:08:20.210Z, perhaps you need `datetime: new Date().toISOString()`.

Comment: Waterline sees the result of `.toISOString()` as `"1"`, a string. It rejects it, as well.

Comment: Damn, I'm out… :-(

Answer (score 0):

Oops. In a previous iteration of the code, I had created the `datetime` value as `Date().now()`. The error I posted was for that. When I changed the code to the version in the question, I forgot that I have to restart Sails **every single time** I change anything because Sails can't figure out that the proper thing to do when a file changes is to reload automatically. So, the problem is solved.